# cakephp: model ignoring underscore in table name before number

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have make an cakephp application but the database i am using is of a crm and i cannot change the table names so it is a restriction. My table name is `emails_users_1_c` . When i tried to call this table name in the model.

It appends the `1` to the users and make it `documents_leads1_c` i dont know why is it happening although i searched on SO and in the documentation but not able to find out.

> Table 'crm.emails_users1_c' doesn't exist".

This is how i am accessing the table.

```
public function makeDocument($data){
        $docuTable = TableRegistry::get('emails_users_1_c');

        $docuData = $docuTable->newEntity($data);

        $docuTable->save($docuData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use such database table names as table class names / aliases, that doesn't work well with the inflection that is applied internally (camelizing followed by underscoring in this specific case). Use meaningful names that follow the CakePHP naming conventions, that will help you the long run.

Ideally create concrete table classes with proper names, for example `UserEmailsTable`, and configure the database table name via `\Cake\ORM\Table::setTable()`:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class UserEmailsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('emails_users_1_c'); // $this->table() before CakePHP 3.4
        // ...
    }
}
```

If for whatever reason concrete table classes can't/shouldn't be used, then configure the aliases on the fly, so that you can still easily reuse them:

```
TableRegistry::config('UserEmails', [
    'table' => 'emails_users_1_c'
]);
```

In any case you should then be able to retrieve the table class instance via the `UserEmails` alias:

```
$UserEmails = TableRegistry::get('UserEmails');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Configuring Table Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-table-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > CakePHP Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)**

Comment: yeah i know this is not a right name but this is made by crm module so i cannot change it i am just making a integration of cake into crm. to change the table name i have go through all the crm module customization process. However if i still want to use i have to use `TableRegistry::config('UserEmails', [
    'table' => 'emails_users_1_c'
]);` ?

Comment: @programmer Sure, I understood that, I'm not saying that you should change the database table name, but the PHP table class name, repectively the CakePHP table alias! Both examples do exactly that, they configure simple class names / aliases, while pointing to the non-conventional database table name.

Comment: very well explained ! Thank you for your help !